# Java Swing - Best Practice - Add/Remove Panels Frequently

Tags: java, performance, swing

I have a Swing-UI with a sub panel that contains a list of persons (within a scroll pane). Each person is represented by a JPanel that consists of an ImageIcon and four JLabels.

The list basically behaves like a circular buffer (with additional conditional behavior) and can be changed via two buttons that can 'rotate' the list back and forth.

```
E.g. forward: [A][B][C][D] -> [B][C][D][A]
```

It usually contains around 15 persons, yet they can be added and removed from within another part of the UI - which then calls the update on the panel as well.

My current solution is to remove all elements from the scroll pane-panel and re-add all the elements (in their new order) after the user has clicked on one of the buttons.

Unfortunately this takes up quite a lot of time. The ImageIcons are cached - so are the Person-JPanels if that person was in the list before, but the part that takes up the most time is the re-adding of said elements.

So my question would be if this could be done in a more efficient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My current solution is to remove all elements from the scroll pane-panel and re-add all the elements

The `Container` API has a method that allows you to add a component at any location in the panel. So to remove a panel from the end and place it at the start, the basic logic would be something like:

```
JPanel removed = panel.getComponent( panel.getComponentCount() - 1);
panel.remove(removed);
panel.add(removed, 0);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

Comment: Unfortunately the remove last, add as first etc-part already happens in the service layer and I actually get two sub lists. The elements that have already been handled in the current iteration and the ones that haven't. Hence I do not know which one has been moved. In addition the persons can be changed from another part of the UI - they could be  removed and new ones added. So I unfortunately do not have the information about what has changed.